# Dockerized nginx isn't serving HTML page

Tags: macos, docker, nginx

Mac OS here, running Docker Version 17.12.0-ce-mac49. I have the following super-simple `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nginx
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I create my Docker image:

```
docker build -t mydocbox .
```

So far so good, no errors. I then create a container from that image:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -d --name mydocbox mydocbox
```

And I see it running (I have confirmed its running by issuing `docker ps` as well as SSHing into the box via `docker exec -it <containerId> bash` and confirming `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html` exists)!

When I open a browser and go to `http://localhost:8080`, I get an empty/blank/nothing-to-see-here screen, not my expected `index.html` page.

I don't see any errors anywhere and nothing to indicate configuration is bad or that firewalls are causing issues. Any ideas as to what the problem could be or how I could troubleshoot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if you can follow [this example](https://github.com/nishanttotla/DockerStaticSite/blob/master/Dockerfile):

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

It uses a [default.conf file](https://github.com/nishanttotla/DockerStaticSite/blob/master/default.conf#L8-L11) which does specify the index.html used

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

Change in the `default.conf` the listening port from 80 to 8080, and EXPOSE it.
Or simply `docker run` with `-p 8080:80` (hostPort:containerPort).